# Searching a string for 2 words occurring concurrently? (Python)

Tags: python, string

I need to check if two words are occurring concurrently. For example:

```
string_im_searching = "John ate a big red apple."
```

I need to know if the string "big red" exists. Alternatively, I would need to know if the string "big" is followed by the string "red"

```
some_other_string = "John is big and the apple is red."
```

The string above should NOT return positive. Yes, it has `"big"` and `"red"` but they are not occurring in the exact positions I need.

Normally if I needed to find a particular string in a sentence I would turn the sentence into a list using `split(" ")` and then iterate through the new list, using `intersection()` to check for the word or words I need. But that method isn't working for me hear, because I'm splitting on empty spaces yet need two words.

Comment: `"big red" in string_im_searching`?

Comment: If `"big"` and `"red"` can only be separated by a `" "` (and it sounds to be the case) then the @OlvinRoght comment does the trick. Or are there other scenarios you'd need to cover?

Answer (score 3):

In python you can just do this

```
if "big red" in string_im_searching:
     #do something
```